# java thread understanding issue

Tags: java, multithreading

Though my question sound like stupid..

Here is code for multiple thread :

```
public class Main {
private int x = -1;

public Main(int xy) {
    this.setX(xy);
}

static Main main;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    main = new Main(10);

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (main) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    main.setX(main.getX() + 10);
                    if (main.getX() >= 40) {
                        try {
                            wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("X : " + main.getX());
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread one = new Thread(runnable);
    one.setName("Hi From One!!");
    one.start();
    Thread two = new Thread(runnable);
    two.setName("Hi From Two!!");
    two.start();
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
```

}

While executing this code I am getting following output:

```
Hi From Two!!<br>
X : 20<br>
X : 30<br>
Exception in thread "Hi From Two!!" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException<br>
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)<br>
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)<br>
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:23)<br>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)<br>
Hi From One!!<br>
Exception in thread "Hi From One!!" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException<br>
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)<br>
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)<br>
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:23)<br>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)<br>
```

I am not getting why it is throwing the `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Here what I am trying to achieve is I want if value of X is grater than 40 same thread should wait and let other to execute.

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: It's thrown from wait. Have you looked up the javadoc to see when wait throws such an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wait` is a function that requires that the calling thread holds the monitor on the target.

In your case, you are calling `this.wait()`, but do not hold the monitor on `this`.

you need to either

```
synchronized (this) {
   wait();
}
```

or

```
main.wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

The call of `object.wait` must synchronized on `object`.

You have called `runnable.wait` but synchronized on `main`.

Try `main.wait();`